# I keep getting error "invalid reference level for size" when trying to plot a multinomial logit in SAS

Tags: sas, multinomial

Im trying to fit a multinomial logit model for this data, but i keep running into the same error. I also want to use the last category as a reference.

```
data foodChoice4;
 input lake $ size $ food $ count;
 datalines;
Hancock <=2.3 Fish 25
Hancock <=2.3 Invertebrate 4 
Hancock <=2.3 Reptile 2 
Hancock <=2.3 Bird 2 
Hancock <=2.3 Other 9 
Hancock >2.3 Fish 8 
Hancock >2.3 Invertebrate 0 
Hancock >2.3 Reptile 1 
Hancock >2.3 Bird 3 
Hancock >2.3 Other 5
Oklawaha <=2.3 Fish 6
Oklawaha <=2.3 Invertebrate 11
Oklawaha <=2.3 Reptile 1
Oklawaha <=2.3 Bird 0
Oklawaha <=2.3 Other 3
Oklawaha >2.3 Fish 15
Oklawaha >2.3 Invertebrate 8
Oklawaha >2.3 Reptile 6
Oklawaha >2.3 Bird 1
Oklawaha >2.3 Other 0
Trafford <=2.3 Fish 5
Trafford <=2.3 Invertebrate 11
Trafford <=2.3 Reptile 2
Trafford <=2.3 Bird 1
Trafford <=2.3 Other 5
Trafford >2.3 Fish 10
Trafford >2.3 Invertebrate 7
Trafford >2.3 Reptile 6
Trafford >2.3 Bird 3
Trafford >2.3 Other 5
George <=2.3 Fish 18
George <=2.3 Invertebrate 19
George <=2.3 Reptile 1
George <=2.3 Bird 2
George <=2.3 Other 3
George >2.3 Fish 20
George >2.3 Invertebrate 1
George >2.3 Reptile 0
George >2.3 Bird 1
George >2.3 Other 3
;
run;



proc logistic data = foodChoice4 plots=all;
  freq count;
  class lake size (ref = "Fish") / param = ref;
  model food = lake size / link = glogit aggregate scale=none;
  output out=out p=pred;
run;
```

I don't even know where to begin here. Tried changing the reference but no luck.

Comment: Variable `size` has value `<=2.3` or `>2.3`, you just used wrong value as the reference level.